# Delete empty array swift

Tags: arrays

I get this array from csv file:

`data = [["Alexandra", "Female", "Club House", "CA", "English", "Drama Club"], ["Andrew", "Male", "Manager", "SD", "Math", "Lacrosse"], ["Anna", "Female", "Manager", "NC", "English", "Basketball"], ["Becky", "Female", "Gym & Fitness", "SD", "Art", "Baseball"], ["Benjamin", "Male", "Club House", "WI", "English", "Basketball"], ["Carl", "Male", "Life Guard", "MD", "Art", "Debate"],[""]]`

i was created one array to save the name and one array to save possiton for an index like this:

```
for index in data {
            employee.append(index[0])
            PosEmployee.append(index[2])
        }
```

when i run it i got error: fatal error: Index out of range
i think because the last  `data` array is an empty array, i am right?

how to clear last empty array?
im try this one in `viewDidLoad`, but this didnt work

```
self.data = Array.filter({$0 != ""})



Help needed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want this?

```
let flat = data.flatMap { $0 }.filter{ $0 != ""}
```

result:
["Alexandra", "Female", "Club House", "CA", "English", "Drama Club", "Andrew", "Male", "Manager", "SD", "Math", "Lacrosse", "Anna", "Female", "Manager", "NC", "English", "Basketball", "Becky", "Female", "Gym & Fitness", "SD", "Art", "Baseball", "Benjamin", "Male", "Club House", "WI", "English", "Basketball", "Carl", "Male", "Life Guard", "MD", "Art", "Debate"]

Comment: actually i need a array like this
```flat = [["Alexandra", "Female", "Club House", "CA", "English", "Drama Club"], ["Andrew", "Male", "Manager", "SD", "Math", "Lacrosse"],[ "Anna", "Female", "Manager", "NC", "English", "Basketball"],...]```

Answer (score 0):

so do you want this?

```
    let flat = [data.flatMap { $0 }.filter{  $0.count > 0  }]
```

result:

[["Alexandra", "Female", "Club House", "CA", "English", "Drama Club", "Andrew", "Male", "Manager", "SD", "Math", "Lacrosse", "Anna", "Female", "Manager", "NC", "English", "Basketb